# Simplifying terms with powers of two

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve a probability problem using an approach (not the approved solution) that leads me to a formula I don't know how to simplify further.  After applying a geometric series, my approach leads to the term $\dfrac{(2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1})}{2^n - 1}$.  With a computer program I have convinced myself that this term equals the much simpler $(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$.  This equivalency looks odd to me and with my limited math skills, I have not been able to simplify $\dfrac{(2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1})}{2^n - 1}$ to $(\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$.  What techniques should I use to simplify $\dfrac{(2 - (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1})}{2^n - 1}$?

Comment: Multiply the numerator by $2^{n-1}$. Compare the result to the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{2-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$

We know $ (a)^b=a^b $

So this reduce to $\dfrac{2-\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}}{2^n-1}$

Take LCM of numerator.

$ \dfrac{\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}}{2^{n}-1} $

Now try to simplify yourself

Comment: Hope you understood it. If you have any doubt do ask in comment

Comment: Ah!  That wasn't hard at all.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dave You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{2-\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{2^n-1}=\frac{2-\dfrac{1}{2^{n-1}}}{2^n-1}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2^n-1}{2^{n-1}}}{2^{n}-1}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$

Comment: Thank you as well!

Comment: @Dave You're welcome :)